NGINX Ingress Controller CORS Issues in Kubernetes
I have set up an Nginx Controller through Helm charts, with two applications running on Kubernetes. Each application has its own Ingress:
App1 Ingress 
App2 Ingress 
Ingress Controller  
When App1 makes requests to App2, it encounters a CORS error, despite having applied CORS settings to App2. Here is my App2 Ingress file.
before the update of Kubernetes version 1.29.6 it was working with same configuration
ON App1-ingress
One issue I noticed is that when I try to add quotes to the configuration and save it, I receive a message saying "no changes made." Additionally, the cors-allow-header annotation appears on two lines, and attempting to consolidate it into one line also results in "no changes made" upon saving. I believe the settings should work without quotes as well, but I am still encountering CORS errors. There are no relevant CORS-related logs in the Ingress NGINX pods, App1 pod, or App2 pod.
I also checked the configuration files inside the Ingress NGINX pod, and there is no CORS-related configuration present.
In summary, I have added CORS settings in two places:
In the values.yaml file, followed by upgrading Ingress NGINX using Helm.
By modifying the App2 Ingress.
Despite these configurations, I am still facing CORS issues. How can I resolve this?
Here is the App2 Ingress file for reference:
App2 ingress:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: dev-test-issuer
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer":"dev-test-issuer","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers":"access-control-allow-origin, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods":"POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, GET, PUT","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin":"*","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors":"true"},"creationTimestamp":"2024-07-30T10:58:46Z","generation":1,"name":"myapplication-ingress","namespace":"dev-testing","resourceVersion":"341461422","uid":"4c498cf4-5aaa-4299-bc89-ca3e5c84b410"},"spec":{"ingressClassName":"nginx","rules":[{"host":"myapplication.dev-testing.k8s-apps.dev-test.int","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"service":{"name":"myapplication-service","port":{"number":8096}}},"path":"/","pathType":"Prefix"}]}}],"tls":[{"hosts":["myapplication.dev-testing.k8s-apps.dev-test.int"],"secretName":"myapplication-ingress-tls"}]},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}}
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: access-control-allow-origin, Origin,
  Authorization, Content-Type
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, GET, PUT
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: '*'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2024-08-02T21:33:46Z"
  generation: 1
  name: myapplication-ingress
  namespace: dev-testing
  resourceVersion: "341465375"
  uid: 33a1fdc2-b3b0-50d6-baec-46b03ce8ed2f
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: myapplication.dev-testing.k8s-apps.dev-test.int
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: myapplication-service
            port:
              number: 8016
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
- myapplication.dev-testing.k8s-apps.dev-test.int
    secretName: myapplication-ingress-tls
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

settings from nginx controller helm value.yaml file:
...
entries:
  proxy-body-size: "2g"  # Maximum size of the client request body
  client-max-body-size: "2g"  # Maximum size of the client request body
  proxy-buffer-size: "2m"  # Buffer size for reading the first part of the response
  proxy-buffers: "16 2m"    # Number and size of buffers for reading the response
  proxy_busy_buffers_size: "2m"
  proxy_buffering: "off"
  enable-cors: "true"
  cors-allow-origin: "*"
  cors-allow-methods: "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
  cors-allow-headers: "DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization"
  large-client-header-buffers: "16 2m"  # Number and size of buffers for large client headers
...


Go through this Stack Link Which might be helpful for you to resolve your issue.

thanks for the link, i forgot to add in question. i got this after updated the kubernetes to 1.29.6 ... in old version it was working with same configurations
